# Running a linux subprocess in python script

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I need to show coloured diff of two text files on linux from my python script, for which I am using vimdiff. I am able to run vimdiff using subprocess but I cant get control back to python script. It stays in the vimdiff mode forever until I do Ctrl+Z.
What i want to do is that open vimdiff and get back to python script after receiving some kind of input from the keyboard. I tried signal module too but couldnt solve the problem.

I am a beginner in python so far what I tried is here:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["vimdiff","test1.txt", "test2.txt"])
try:
 p.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
 p.kill()
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What happens when you `:q` out of vim?

Comment: @NPE It still says in vim mode but i see the files in black and white ,instead of colour.

Comment: what about `qa!`, does it still stays in vim?

Comment: @dlmeetei No, it gets out of vim.

Answer (score 0):

As I known vim uses ncurses library. 
For run ncurses based application use module [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html):

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn("vim")
child.interact()
```

Comment: Explain why this is necessary.

Comment: @Linch could you explain little more as of what to expect after vimdiff command executes as it stays in vim mode.

Answer (score 0):

`vim` is a full screen text mode program that does tricks with screen. Avoid piping its input/output. Better run

```
subprocess.call(["vimdiff", "test1.txt", "test2.txt"])
```

or simply

```
os.system("vimdiff test1.txt test2.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried that but again the problem stays because i cant exit from vimdiff from my script without doing Ctrl+Z.